# слайдер Slick- Slider Syncing - infinite увеличивает количество блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использовала слайдер Slick - Slider Syncing, обнаружила неприятную особенность...Если задать свойство  infinite: true, то слайдер автоматически умножает количество слайдов на 2!
Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то поставить это свойство без добавление блоков? 
В моем проекте это были превьюшки картинок, пути который задавались динамически, и добавление блоков стало проблемой. 
Спасибо

Comment: Что значит "пути который задавались динамически"?

Comment: это значит что путь формировался исходя из того, какую вкладку пользователь нажал при помощи jquery. Конечно можно переписать код и запускать цикл по второму разу, если количество блоков больше, чем картинок в папке. Но меня больше интересует можно ли как-то убрать это свойство слайдера.